# How to get CardType / Payment Network Type for Android Pay

Tags: android, android-pay

Currently :

```
maskedWallet.getPaymentDescriptions()[0].substring(0,maskedWallet.getPaymentDescriptions()[0].indexOf("-"));
```

would give me Card Type(VISA/AMEX/MASTERCARD/DISCOVER). 
Eg: `maskedWallet.getPaymentDescriptions()[0]`  has String value "VISA-1008".

Above method is throwing index out of bounds exception when "-" is not found.

Now I have updated the code to get the Payment Network Type/Card Type from dpan (virtual account # given by Android Pay), using the same method which gives us Card Type based on the Credit Card Number (here I used dpan instead of CC#).

I wanted to know if there is any better way to get CardType if its an Android Pay Transaction?

Answer (score -1):

From MaskedWallet object received in onActivityResults(){}

```
String card_type = mMaskedWallet.getInstrumentInfos()[0].getInstrumentType();
String card_num = mMaskedWallet.getInstrumentInfos()[0].getInstrumentDetails();

String cardholder_name =  mMaskedWallet.getBuyerBillingAddress().getName();
```

For more information please refer to documentation:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/MaskedWallet.html#getInstrumentInfos()